# Отрисовка кнопки tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Прошу совета,
цель: отрисовать кнопку со своими эффектами, например с рамкой определенной толщины,
необходимость: нужно написать/наследовать только на основе Tkinter или любых других встроенных в python средств.
Видимые варианты:
1 - поверх Label повесить button меньшего размера на толщину рамки.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
def myButton():
    l = Label(tk,bg="red")
    l.place(width=32,height=32)
    b = Button(l,bg="blue",width=28,height=28)
    b.pack(expand=1, padx=1, pady=1)
myButton()
tk.mainloop()
```

2 - создать кнопку на основе canvas (прямоугольник поверх рисунка) и прописать обработку нажатий клавиш мыши

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
def myButton():
    canvas.create_rectangle(3,3,31,31, fill="blue")
    canvas.create_rectangle(2,2,32,32, outline="red")
myButton()
tk.mainloop()
```

что посоветуете? может еще какой вариант есть?
что лучше? что функциональней? что меньше нагружает программу?

Comment: а что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: 1 и 2(без обработки нажатий) вариант.

Comment: и что, 1 или 2 меньше нагружает программу ?

Comment: я как бы с этим вопросом и обращаюсь... когда одна кнопка вроде все хорошо, но когда их десятки или сотни... ? как определить что лучше а что нет?

Comment: а как определить что лучше а что нет?  если вы не показываете реализации того что вы пробовали.

Comment: добавил в вопрос, только во 2 примере обработку нажатия клавиши не написал....

Comment: неужели нет никаких других вариантов?

Comment: В первом случае можно без кнопки - просто Label с рамкой и нужным фоном, и вешаете обработчик клика мыши. Во втором случае не нужно два прямоугольника - достаточно одного с рамкой и фоном.

Comment: insolor, я так понимаю в Label нет возможности изменить цвет border, а значит и результата нужно добиваться иначе...

Comment: За толщину рамки отвечает bd
```
Button(text='Текст', bd=5)
```